# How do i change Console output of compiler

Tags: gcc, localization, locale

i want to change the compiled ( *which is usually in english*) console output in GCC compiler on linux  to other local languaue (such as HINDi, chineese ).. i would like to do this in c/c++ language. please guide me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking to change the language of the gcc messages or to change the language of a program compiled with gcc?

Comment: Thanks for reply..       To be simple i want to change the output messages of gcc for example if i use printf("Hello World "); which is in english i want display same Hello world on output window in other languages like french, spanish,hindi,chinese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at the [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) tool [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/s/gettext).  Basically you mark all the text that you might wish to translate at some point with a macro, _("Some text here"), this has to uses:

1. Allows the source code to be scanned to make a .pot file of potential translations
2. Calls a translate function that returns the translation if there is one available or the original string otherwise.

You can then as a separate operation and post compilation/delivery get translators to use the .pot file to provide .po files for specific locales, (language/location combinations), these are then compiled into .mo files that can be added to a specified directory structure.  At run time i18n code will look at those locations to try to load the appropriate translations for your location with the clever bit of working up from your exact language & location, your language, the original text.

Comment: can you please suggest any tutorial or link.

Comment: please tell what all the necessary packages to be present in gcc complier for the localization